# Converting Python code to PHP

Tags: php, python

What is the following Python code in PHP?

```
import sys

li = range(1,777);

def countFigure(li, n):
        m = str(n);
        return str(li).count(m);

# counting figures
for substr in range(1,10):
        print substr, " ", countFigure(li, substr);
```

Wanted output for 777

```
1   258
2   258
3   258
4   258
5   258
6   258
7   231
8   147
9   147
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I did any Python but I think this should do it.
If you could clarify what `str(li)` looks like it would help.

```
<?php

$li = implode('', range(1, 776));

function countFigure($li, $n)
{
    return substr_count($li, $n);
}

// counting figures

foreach (range(1, 9) as $substr)
    echo $substr, " ", countFigure($li, $substr), "\n";
```